# Invalid character in a Base-64 string when Concatenating and Url encoding a string

Tags: c#, asp.net

I’m trying to write some encryption code that is passed through a *Url*. For the sake of the issue I’ve excluded the actual encryption of the data and just shown the code causing the problem.

I take a salt value, convert it to a byte array and then convert that to a *base64* string. This string I concatenate to another *base64* string (which was previously a byte array).

These two *base64* strings are then *Url* encoded.  Here’s my code...

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Security.Cryptography;
using System.IO;
using System.Web;

class RHEncryption
{
    private static readonly Encoding ASCII_ENCODING = new System.Text.ASCIIEncoding();
    private static readonly string SECRET_KEY = "akey";
    private static string md5(string text)
    {
        return BitConverter.ToString(new MD5CryptoServiceProvider().ComputeHash(ASCII_ENCODING.GetBytes(text))).Replace("-", "").ToLower();
    }

    public string UrlEncodedData;

    public RHEncryption()
    {
        // encryption object
        RijndaelManaged aes192 = new RijndaelManaged();
        aes192.KeySize = 192;
        aes192.BlockSize = 192;            
        aes192.Mode = CipherMode.CBC;
        aes192.Key = ASCII_ENCODING.GetBytes(md5(SECRET_KEY));
        aes192.GenerateIV();

        // convert Ivector to base64 for sending            
        string base64IV = Convert.ToBase64String(aes192.IV);

        // salt value
        string s = "maryhadalittlelamb";
        string salt = s.Substring(0, 8);
        // convert to byte array
        // and base64 for sending
        byte[] saltBytes = ASCII_ENCODING.GetBytes(salt.TrimEnd('\0'));
        string base64Salt = Convert.ToBase64String(saltBytes);

        //url encode concatenated base64 strings
        UrlEncodedData = HttpUtility.UrlEncode(base64Salt + base64IV, ASCII_ENCODING);
    }

    public string UrlDecodedData()
    {
        // decode the url encode string
        string s = HttpUtility.UrlDecode(UrlEncodedData, ASCII_ENCODING);

        // convert back from base64
        byte[] base64DecodedBytes = null;
        try
        {
            base64DecodedBytes = Convert.FromBase64String(s);
        }
        catch (FormatException e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(e.Message.ToString());
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
        return s;
    }
}
```

If I then call the **UrlDecodedData** method I get a

> Invalid character in a Base-64 string

exception.  This is generated because the *base64Salt* variable contains an invalid character (I’m guessing a line termination) but I can’t seem to strip it off.

Update 1

One thing I’ve found since posting is that if I change the order of string to be encoded no exception is raised.
So changing the following code from

```
UrlEncodedData = HttpUtility.UrlEncode(base64Salt + base64IV, ASCII_ENCODING);
```

To

```
UrlEncodedData = HttpUtility.UrlEncode(base64IV + base64Salt, ASCII_ENCODING);
```

Seems to work, unfortunately I can’t reorder as this information is passed to a third party component.

Comment: It is sheer luck that `base64IV + base64Salt` happened to not break that time. In general catenating Base64 strings may not give you a Base64 string, so don't do it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is your problem:

```
UrlEncodedData = HttpUtility.UrlEncode(base64Salt + base64IV, ASCII_ENCODING);
...
string s = HttpUtility.UrlDecode(UrlEncodedData, ASCII_ENCODING);
base64DecodedBytes = Convert.FromBase64String(s);
```

You are catenating two Base64-encoded strings then trying to Base64-decode the combination. This will only work if your `base64Salt` is a multiple of six bits, and in your case it is not. Data not such a multiple gets Base64-encoded with a trailing '=' character, catenating it puts the '=' in the middle of the string, which is not a valid Base64 string.

You have to catenate the original data before encoding it. This will only work if you know the original data lengths. If you do not, you will have to encode the salt and vector separately, and catenate them to the URL; e.g. http://yoursite/yourPage?salt=mcMDaw%20VUsZX&iv=VUsZXyg6n61e6SavmMrtAWa0A

Comment: @Dour thanks for replying. Should i concatenate and then convert to base64?

Comment: You can do that if you will always know where to split the decoded byte[] into salt and vector. In your example the salt is the first 8 bytes. Will this always be true forever and cannot ever change? If so, catenate, encode, decode, then split out the first 8 bytes again. If there is any possibility this could ever change, you will have to encode them separately. Or you could add a byte prefix saying how many bytes are salt. E.g. byte[] = { 32, 12, 104, 74, ... } means the first 32 bytes are the salt.

Comment: i'm lucky this time that the byte array offsets are fixed.